# Loop over Pandas dataframe to populate list (Python)

Tags: pandas, list, for-loop

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
action = ['include','exclude','ignore','include', 'exclude', 'exclude','ignore']
names = ['john','michael','joshua','peter','jackson','john', 'erick']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(action,names)), columns = ['action','names'])
```

I also have a list of starting participants like this:

```
participants = [['michael','jackson','jeremiah','martin','luis']]
```

I want to iterate over df['action']. If `df['action'] == 'include'`, add another list to the participants list that includes all previous names and the one in df['names']. So, after the first iteration, participants list should look like this:

```
participants = [['michael','jackson','jeremiah','martin','luis'],['michael','jackson','jeremiah','martin','luis','john']]
```

I have managed to achieve this with the following code (I don´t know if this part could be improved, although it is not my question):

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[i,'action'] == 'include':
        person = [df.at[i,'names']]
        old_list = participants[-1]
        new_list = old_list + person
        participants.append(new_list)
    else:
        pass
```

The main problem (and my question is), how do I accomplish the same but removing the name when `df['action'] == 'exclude'`? So, after the second iteration, I should have this list in participants:

```
participants = [['michael','jackson','jeremiah','martin','luis'],['michael','jackson','jeremiah','martin','luis','john'],['jackson','jeremiah','martin','luis','john']]
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a elif to your code. With the [remove](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method you can remove a item by value. Just be careful your person is a list and not a string. I just call it by index with [0].

```
    elif df.at[i, 'action'] == 'exclude':
        person = [df.at[i, 'names']]
        participants.append(participants[-1].remove(person[0]))
```